# Each key must be a number of string; got undefined protractor

Tags: javascript, json, protractor

I am trying to read data from json file but I have some trouble.
How can I get items from a json file to individual items?

My json file:

```
[
 {
  "UserName": "test@test.en",
  "Password": "tests123"
 }
]
```

My method:

```
element(by.name('username')).sendKeys(browser.params.UserName);
element(by.name('password')).sendKeys(browser.params.Password);
```

as a result i get

```
Failed: each key must be a number of string; got undefined
```

Comment: browser.params[0].UserName assuming `browser.params = [
 {
  "UserName": "test@test.en",
  "Password": "tests123"
 }
]`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are passing an array of object and not an object, thus, you have to be precise in your variable.

Either directly pass an object

```
{
  "UserName": "test@test.en",
  "Password": "tests123"
}
```

Or specify the index in the array

```
element(by.name('username')).sendKeys(browser.params[0].UserName);
element(by.name('password')).sendKeys(browser.params[0].Password);
```

Answer (score 0):

My Test was also failing with json file then i converted my datafile into ts file like below

```
export const DataForSearch =
{
    Login:
    { 
        CorrectCreds: { username: 'test@test.en', password: 'tests123' }
    }

};
```

then use this in my test case like

```
    import {DataForSearch } from "../DataLogin"

const using = require("jasmine-data-provider");

describe("Login Page", () => {
    using(DataForSearch.Login, (data: any, alldesc: any) => {
    it("Login", () => {
    element(by.name('username')).sendKeys(data.username);
    element(by.name('password')).sendKeys(data.password);
    })
    })
})
```

you can try typescript file, if you still facing issue.If you face any issue let me know