# Reading data from file protractor

Tags: javascript, node.js, protractor

I have a file config.ts where I have saved login and password

config.ts
"UserName": "test@test.en",
"Password": "pass123"

with json file i am downloading the data as below. How can I get data from config.ts file?

My method:

```
login() {
 element(by.name('username')).sendKeys(browser.params[0].UserName);
 element(by.name('password')).sendKeys(browser.params[0].Password);
 browser.sleep(5000);
}
```

My test

```
it('login page', () => {
 page.login();
});
```

Comment: didnt you just post this exact question a few hours ago? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46337889/each-key-must-be-a-number-of-string-got-undefined-protractor

Answer (score 1):

You can define params object in config.ts. The params object will be passed directly to the Protractor instance, and can be accessed from your test as browser.params.

[Config.ts](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/config.ts)

[How to use param object](https://moduscreate.com/protractor_parameters_adding_flexibility_automation_tests/)

Answer (score 0):

I dunno what you mean by "config.ts where I have saved login and password"... but if its not working then I suppose you didnt do it properly.  For something be accessible within `browser.params`, you have to add it to that specific property.

Inside config.ts:

```
params: {
    username: 'hi',
    password: '123'
}
```

With the way I have in the example, you would access it via `browser.params.username`

Comment: I get: "Cannot find module 'config'" I try to appeal in the following way: require('config');

Comment: you don't have to require your config.  you should review the protractor docs a little more, you are misunderstanding basic functionality of the tool... http://www.protractortest.org/#/api-overview